How to show a grid of four equally sized Cards?
I need to place the cards on the screen like in the image, but I can't and I don't know why. I've tried with and without a function, with and without columns and rows. I'm new to jetpack compose and I'm just following the Android studio course with jetpack compose, and this is an exercise in arranging images/cards on the screen
exercise
What I am trying to achieve:

This is my code so far:
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        setContent {
            CardTheme {
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
                ){
                    MainScreen()
                }

            }
        }
    }
}


@Composable
fun MainScreen(){
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
            .padding(16.dp)
    ) {
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .weight(1f)
                .fillMaxSize(),

        ) {
            Card(
                title = "Titulo",
                description = "Descriçao",
                backGroundColor = Color(0xFFEADDFF),
                modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)
                    .fillMaxHeight()

            )
            Card(
                title = "Titulo 2",
                description = "Descrição 2",
                backGroundColor = Color(0xFFD0BCFF),
                modifier = Modifier
                    .weight(1f)
                    .fillMaxHeight()
            )

        }
        Row (
            modifier = Modifier
                .weight(1f)
                .fillMaxWidth(),
        ){
            Card(
                title = "Titulo 3",
                description = "Descrição 3",
                backGroundColor = Color(0xFFB69DF8),
                modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)
                    .fillMaxHeight()
            )
            Card(
                title = "Titulo 4",
                description = "Descrição 4",
                backGroundColor = Color(0xFFF6EDFF),
                modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)
                    .fillMaxHeight()
            )

        }


    }

}


@Composable
private fun Card(
    title: String,
    description: String,
    backGroundColor: Color,
    modifier: Modifier
){
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(16.dp)
            .background(backGroundColor),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        Text(
            text = title,
            modifier = Modifier.padding(bottom = 16.dp),
            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold
        )
        Text(
            text = description,
            textAlign = TextAlign.Justify
        )
    }
}

I tried using all the modifier =Modifier functions I know and some new ones for me, but I still couldn't get the result I wanted. My current output looks like this:


Welcome to stackoverflow! If an answer solved your problem, you can mark it as accepted answer by clicking the checkmark button at the left side of that answer. Thank you!

You are almost there. The only issue is, you are passing a Modifier to your Card Composable, but in your Card, you don't do anything with that Modifier that was passed in.
You should usually apply any passed in Modifier to the first child Composable:

It's a best practice to have all of your composables accept a modifier parameter, and pass that modifier to its first child that emits UI.

You need to adjust your code like this:
@Composable
private fun Card(
    title: String,
    description: String,
    backGroundColor: Color,
    modifier: Modifier
) {
    Column(
        modifier = modifier  // use the passed in Modifier here
            .padding(16.dp)  // apply other Modifiers afterwards
            .background(backGroundColor),
        //...
    ) {
        //...
    }
}

To also make the Card usable without passing any custom Modifier, you should assign a default Modifier in the function signature:
@Composable
private fun Card(
    // ...
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier  // if no Modifier is passed in, use default empty Modifier
) {
    //...
}

Output:


Hint:
The resulting code will almost look like the target image, with one small difference regarding the padding. Check your Modifier ordering to fix this.

ty for your help, I think I understand now. When I define the Modifier within the Card function, I overwrite the modifier passed as an argument in the called function, is that it?

Almost. If you pass a Modifier to Card, it does not do anything yet. It will only have an effect if you apply it somewhere. In your previous code, you were using a fresh Modifier for the Column inside of the Card and were ignoring the Modifier that was passed in. What you want to do is to apply the passed in modifier on the Column. I hope that explanation makes sense!
